# Visual Studio dynamic javascript reference intellisense from localhost

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, dynamic, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

It appears that Visual Studio 2010 will skip references that are not formatted http://x.x... I'm trying to use

```
/// <reference path="http://localhost:12946/js/fancytest" />
```

to generate intellisense for a dynamic javascript result without going through the hassle of setting up a subdomain.

I've used fiddler and found that Visual Studio is entirely ignoring my reference if I don't include a subdomain. No request to my script controller is attempted.

Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: Does adding an entry to the hosts file for a fictional subdomain work?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I was hoping to not have to set up a subdomain.

Comment: You're not actually setting up a subdomain. You're just mapping some fictional domain name like "static-files.localhost.com" to "127.0.0.1", and then using that (non-existent) domain in the URL. So long as you have a default, catch-all website set up in IIS, it should work.

Comment: My question was probably worded poorly. I'll edit it soon. I simply mean I don't want to have to touch my hosts file or IIS for a solution. It will work if I use a subdomain for the files, but I was hoping there would be a something I was not understanding about how Visual Studio pulls javascript references.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lvh.me which points to 127.0.0.1.

It works in VS2012